# install4j invalid PNG file for splash screen

Tags: png, install4j

I made a minor edit (with GIMP) to the PNG file used as a splash screen with install4j. install4j now fails with the following stack trace and error:

install4j: compilation failed. Reason: com.A.B.E: com.A.B.E: File splash.png is not a valid image file.

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.bmp.BMPImageWriter.write(BMPImageWriter.java:230)
        at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:598)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1479)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1521)
        at com.A.B.D.U(ejt:3266)
        at com.A.B.D.R(ejt:3578)
        at com.A.B.D.M(ejt:3204)
        at com.A.B.D.O(ejt:1707)
        at com.A.B.D.d(ejt:534)
        at com.install4j.C.D.F.D(ejt:1952)
        at com.install4j.C.D.B.X(ejt:1313)
        at com.install4j.C.C.W(ejt:873)
        at com.install4j.C.C.B(ejt:230)
        at com.install4j.C.A.A(ejt:1782)
        at com.install4j.C.B.º(ejt:518)
        at com.install4j.C.B.Ä(ejt:937)
        at com.install4j.C.B.I(ejt:1116)
        at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.ő(ejt:851)
        at com.A.L.Ŀ(ejt:1343)
        at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:2655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.install4j.runtime.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

What would have changed in the PNG file to cause it to fail when everything was working fine before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere along the line PNG images with transparency are not supported. An alpha channel had been added to my PNG file and once I removed it everything worked fine again.